# git rebase failed with "fatal: cannot combine apply options with merge options"

Tags: git, git-rebase

I want to use this git command

```
git rebase -X theirs --onto new-repo --committer-date-is-author-date commit_id master
```

but this error occurs

> fatal: cannot combine apply options with merge options

Can someone explain this to me?

(Git Version 2.26.2.windows.1 on Windows 10)

Comment: The version of Git you are using (and ideally, your OS) would be great info for people that would want to help you ;)

Comment: @philb Oh, I'm sorry, I'm new to stackoverflow, I forgot to add that information. I'm using Git version 2.26.2.windows.1 on Windows 10

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, make sure to upgrade to the [latest Git for Windows](https://github.com/git-for-windows/git/releases) (2.39.1)

The actual error message would [now read](https://github.com/git/git/blame/2fc9e9ca3c7505bc60069f11e7ef09b1aeeee473/builtin/rebase.c#L1488):

```
apply options and merge options cannot be used together
```

In your case:

- `-X<option>` is a merge strategy, involving the rebase "merge backend"
- `--onto`  is an apply option, , involving the rebase "apply backend"

Since you cannot have both backend for the same rebase operation, you get that error message.

Comment: I suggest a [different approach here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75294326/6309)

Answer (score 1):

In my case the issue was previously unfinished apply operation.

This is what helped me to resolve it:

```
rm -r ".git/rebase-apply"
```

Comment: That solved it for me. The error came up out of nowhere, never seen it before in 1 trillion rebases. Thanks!